# How to minify Javascript if you use SBT 0.10 or later

Tags: javascript, scala, obfuscation, sbt

How do you minify or obfuscate your Javascript files, if you build your Scala projects with [Simple Build Tool (SBT) 0.10.x](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki)?

*Edit:* Or later SBT versions, e.g. 0.11, 0.12.

(For earlier versions of SBT there are some plugins that minify/obfuscate Javascript, but as far as I can tell they haven't been upgraded to work with SBT 0.10.x. Two examples: [Yui Compressor Plugin for SBT](https://github.com/hoffrocket/sbt-yui), and  [sbt-closure](https://github.com/davegurnell/sbt-closure/))

([Here's a list of SBT 0.10.x plugins](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/sbt-0.10-plugins-list); I didn't find any plugin that minifies Javascript.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt-closure has a [recently active branch](https://github.com/davegurnell/sbt-closure/commits/sbt011) that is targetting SBT 0.11 compatibility. You could wait for that to be completed, or, better yet, contribute! The [SBT Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/simple-build-tool) or #sbt on Freenode IRC are good places to find help for plugin development.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably wait for sbt-closure for SBT 0.11 to be completed.

Answer (score 2):

In the interests of staying up to date, here's an actively-developed [fork](https://github.com/eltimn/sbt-closure#acknowledgements) of the 'sbt-closure' plugin:

https://github.com/eltimn/sbt-closure

It's published to TypeSafe's [Community Ivy Repository](http://www.scala-sbt.org/community-plugins.html#communityrepo) and is [currently has builds](http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-closure) against sbt versions 0.11.2, 0.11.3 and 0.12.0.

This question was originally about sbt 0.10.x, but I think later versions are probably of more interest by now.

Comment: Yes I use SBT 0.12 or 0.13 now. I changed the title to "SBT 0.10 or later" so other people will find your answers, which actually concern versions > 0.10 :-)